# FakeItEasy Reset calls to an object

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, fakeiteasy

I use fake it easy to generate fakes for my object. Now I test if some of the methods on the fake objects where called. The thing is I want for each unit test to reset the state of the fake back to original state.

I need this because I generate the fakes once for each unit test class so I would need to somehow reset the call state.

This is how my code looks like:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_Process_SampleMessageNEW_Should_Call_ISampleMessageConverter_GetRouteObject()
    {
        //Arrange
        //should reset the state of the fakes, _sampleRouteConvertor and _orderDalcMock are fakes
        _sampleRouteConvertor.BackToRecord();
        _orderDalcMock.BackToRecord();
        A.CallTo(() => _orderDalcMock.GetOrder(A<IRQOrderIDCriteria>.Ignored))
            .Returns(new OrderDTO() {Id = nextId++});
        SampleMessage sampleMessage = SampleMessageTestHelpers.GetSavedSampleMessage();
        sampleMessage.MaterialId = CacheMaterials.GetMaterials()[0].Code;
        sampleMessage.MessageType = "NEW";

        //Act
        SampleMessageProcessor sampleMessageProcessor = new SampleMessageProcessor(sampleMessage);
        sampleMessageProcessor.Process();

        //Assert
        A.CallTo(() => _sampleRouteConvertor.GetRouteObject(A<RoutineSample>.Ignored, A<List<ICacheTrackArea>>.Ignored))
            .MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not build new Fakes for each test?  That will solve the problem.

If setting up the new fake every time is a complicated chunk of code, write a helper function to setup the new fake.

Comment: You also have the set up ([TestInitialize]) and tear down (       [TestCleanup]) methods.